# Laravel Eloquent - updating a field in a relation

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

I'm looking for a better way of writing this. I feel like there must be a better way?

```
public static function logClick($lid)
{
     $clickId = link::find($lid);

     $clicks = click::find($clickId->click_id);

     $c = $clicks->clicks;
     $c++;

     $clicks->clicks = $c;
     $clicks->save();

     return $clicks;
 }
```

Models:

```
class link extends Model
{
    public function click()
    {
        return $this->hasOne('App\click', 'id' ,'click_id');
    }

}

class click extends Model
{
    public function link()
    {
        return $this->hasOne('App\link');
    }
}
```

**Btw. everything works, just looking to improve my code writing :)**

Comment: your model please

Comment: Added my model's :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
public static function logClick($lId){
    click::whereHas('link', function($q)use($lId){
        $q->where('id', $lId);
    })
    ->increment('clicks');
}
```

This should do

EDIT: if you want to return the clicks number

```
public static function logClick($lId){
        $click = click::whereHas('link', function($q)use($lId){
            $q->where('id', $lId);
        })
        ->increment('clicks');
        return $click->clicks;
    }
```

This one liner has the advantage of being a single query. In case `$q->where('id', $lId);` doesn't work, make sure to use `$q->where('links_table_name.id', $lId);`

Answer (score 1):

```
public static function logClick($lid)
{
    $clicks = link::find($lid)->click;
    $clicks->increment('clicks');
    return $clicks;
}
```